# Считать 2 последние буквы строки

Tags: c++

Необходимо считать в отдельную переменную 2 последние буквы строки.

Например
`I love you` => `ou`
`Hello` => `lo`

Если в строке последнее слово состоит из одного символа вывести "NO"

Например
`Blabla a` => `NO`

Comment: Так а в чём сложность?

Comment: str.subst(str.length()-2,2) где str имеет тип string.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka ну и проверку на пробел добавить ;-)

Comment: @HasmickGaryaka это считывается в отдельную переменную? Или просто выводится на экран

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() 
{
    std::string s;
    std::getline (std::cin, s);

    if(s.size() < 2) { /* Error */ }

    std::string part = s.substr(s.length() - 2, 2);

    if(isalpha(part[1]) && isspace(part[0])) // 1 letter
        std::cout << "NO" << std::endl; 
    else
        std::cout << part << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

const char* str_2(char instr[])
{
    instr+=strlen(instr)-2;
    if (instr[0]==' ') 
        return ("NO");
    return instr;
}

int main() {
    cout << "***: " << str_2("i love you") << "\n";
    cout << "***: " << str_2("Blabla a") << "\n";
return 0;
}

/*

***: ou
***: NO

*/
```

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/GopeKT

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char s[256];

  while (fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin))
  {
    int len = strlen(s);
    if (s[len-1]=='\n') s[--len] = 0;
    char *p = max<char*>(s + len - 2, s);
    puts(p);
  } 

  return 0;
}
```